# codeigniter apply date on field name (of timestamp) and compare with year

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Normal mysql query is

```
select * from recordstable where YEAR(dateline) = 2014;
```

Table is as follows:

```
 recordid dateline status
 _________________________
    1     1388534400   1
    2     1188534400   2
```

I would like to get the records that are of this year.  this is what i know

```
$this->db->get_where('recordstable',array('dateline'=>2014));
```

Now, how to apply year on the columnname dateline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is stored as unix timestamp and hence using `year()` will return NULL.
You need to use `from_unixtime()` to get the real date and then the year

```
mysql> select year('1388534400');
+------------------+
| year('1388534400') |
+------------------+
|             NULL |
+------------------+

mysql> select year(from_unixtime('1388534400'));
+-----------------------------------+
| year(from_unixtime('1388534400')) |
+-----------------------------------+
|                              2014 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Then in CI you will need to pass the where condition as

```
array('Year(from_unixtime(dateline))'=>2014
```

Comment: Oh..exactly, was getting null when i put year...this one works perfect.